# Non homogeneous Sturm-Liouville problem and solution: Is the solution given in terms of $\lambda$, not particular eigenvalues?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Standard form of non homogeneous S.L.

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(p(x)y'(x))+(q(x)+\lambda r(x))y(x)=f(x)\tag1$$ with Boundary Conditions: let's say $(0<x<1)$+ B.C.

The derivation of the solution is given as following, if you know this you can skip.

> For example we found the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions solving ***homogeneous S.L.***: $\lambda_n\to \phi_n(x)$
>
> and we assume that solution can be in form of these eigenfunctions. Such that $$y(x)=\displaystyle\sum_n^\infty a_n\phi_n(x)\tag2$$
>
> Playing with eq (1)
>   $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(p(x)y'(x))+(q(x)+\lambda_n r(x)+\lambda r(x)-\lambda_n r(x))y(x)=f(x)$$
>
> And plugging into the assuming solution (2)
>
> $$\displaystyle\sum_n^\infty a_n \left\{\underbrace{\dfrac{d}{dx}(p(x)\phi_n'(x))+(q(x)+\lambda_n r(x))\phi_n(x)}_{0}+(\lambda r(x)-\lambda_n r(x))\phi_n(x)\right\}=f(x)$$
>
> Then:
>
> $$\displaystyle\sum_n^\infty a_n(\lambda-\lambda_n)r(x)\phi_n(x)=f(x) \tag3$$
>
> > and using orthogonality property:
> >
> > $$\displaystyle\int_0^1r(x)\phi_n(x)\phi_m(x)dx=\delta_{mn}$$
>
> Then from eq (3) we get $$a_n=\dfrac1{(\lambda-\lambda_n)}\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)\phi_n(x)dx\tag4$$
>
> So we have the solution:
>
> $$y(x)=\displaystyle\sum_n^\infty \left\{\dfrac{\phi_n(x)}{(\lambda-\lambda_n)}\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)\phi_n(x)dx\right\}\tag5$$

***Question:*** What is work of $\lambda$ in the eq (5)? What is the difference between $\lambda$ and $\lambda_n$, do we just left the solution like this?

Comment: And how can I test this is whether a real general solution or not?

Comment: What do you mean by a **general solution** of a nonhomogeneous Sturm-Liouville problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $\lambda$, you can solve the equation for all $f$ *if and only if* $\lambda$ is not one of the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$. The solution as a function of $\lambda$ is holomorphic with single order poles at every eigenvalue. The residue at an eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ is the projection of $f$ onto the eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_n$. The sum of all the residues is the Fourier series for $f$ in the orthogonal eigenvectors $\phi_n$.

Here's an interesting bit of History: These facts led to one of the earliest proofs of the completeness of the eigenfunctions of such an equation. This was done by trading all the residues in the finite plane for one residue at $\infty$, which happens to be $f$; and this must equal the sum of all the residues in the finite plane, which is the Fourier series for $f$ in the eigenvectors of the Sturm-Liouville operator.